# How can I display the NA values in a column (inside a dataframe) in R and how can I change given values to NA. Refer to attached image

Tags: r

I tried the below codes. The first code gives me a lot of rows with FALSE FALSE FALSE, the second code gives me 0 rows and same with the third line, it gives me 0 rows as well. Any guidance appreciated

```
is.na(obes$Rate)
obes%>%filter(NA %in% 'Rate')
obes%>%filter(is.na('Rate'))
```

[image]

Comment: The image shows `No data` as a string and not `NA`.  Perhaps you want `obes %>% filter(Rate != 'No data')` or if it is real NA, then `obes %>% filter(is.na(Rate))` without quoting the `Rate`

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also show expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to quote the column names inside `tidyverse` functions.  Using a small reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
```

Assign `NA` into some elements

```
iris$Sepal.Length[5] <- NA
```

Using a string as column name, return 0 rows because it is not getting evaluated

```
iris %>% 
   filter(is.na('Sepal.Length'))
[#1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

With the correct syntax, i.e. unquoted column names

```
iris %>% 
   filter(is.na(Sepal.Length))
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           NA         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

If we want to use a string, convert it to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
iris %>% 
   filter(is.na(!!rlang::sym('Sepal.Length')))
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           NA         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answer. I tried loading the iris data to have a go and it loaded, but when I copy paste in what you answered, it returns 0 rows for me. I tried this one ``` iris %>% 
   filter(is.na(Sepal.Length))

Comment: @Malan have you created some NA elements like `iris$Sepal.Length[5] <- NA`